# checkbox running script onclick before actually setting the checked flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, telerik

I have a combobox with checkboxes. I am using jQuery to add a Click event to all of the checkboxes. When the checkbox is checked, a script is supposed to run and check an attribute of the checked box to determine it's type and then perform functions accordingly:

```
function () {
    $('.RcbTag').find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var evtCB = $(this);
        var id = $(this).closest(".rcbSlide").siblings(".RcbTag").attr("id");
        var rcbObject = $find(id);

        rcbObject.get_items().forEach(
        function (item, index) {
            if (item.get_attributes().getAttribute('GUIDType') == 'group' &&
                item.get_checked()) {
                alert("Checked");
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem right now is that it appears that the script is running before the checkbox is actually flipped to "checked". So in this example, it looks to see if the item attribute is 'group' and if it's checked. This always returns false, but will return true when I uncheck it. So I'm missing some order of events here. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing jQuery click handlers and the Telerik code.  Let's try and just stick with the Telerik-sanctioned events and I think everything will work like you're expecting.

On your RadComboBox, add an event handler declaritively like this:

```
OnClientItemChecked = "ComboBoxRowClick"
```

Then declare the JS function as you have it now (except we want to name it and not keep it anonymous):

```
function ComboBoxRowClick(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_item().get_attributes().getAttribute('GUIDType') == 'group' &&
        args.get_item().get_checked()) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
}
```

For more info on the client side functions from Telerik, you can check this link: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listboxitem-client-api.html

Also, you might run into this small annoyance where you have to click in the little checkbox itself, and not anywhere on the row (as one might expect).  You can find a workaround for that one here: http://www.msigman.com/2010/07/telerik-radlistbox-fix/

Answer (score 0):

try using `change` instead of `click`? that way you will catch changes made via keybord as well. and it will solve ypur problem.

Comment: you are using `get_checked` and `get_items` - thats not part of jQuery. do you have jstree or something else added? are there any js-errors in the console?

Comment: get_checked and get_items are part of the telerik control object which is a combobox with checkboxes